# Highchart Axis with only min and max series value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In the charts of our application, we would like to avoid polluting the screen with too much information.

We need to have an axis that displays only the lowest and highest value.

Does anybody know how to do that with Highchart?

That would then be something like that

[image: Chart as we want to see it]

PS: ignore the vertical gray bands behind the chart, that's a totally unrelated.

Comment: There are probably a number of ways. I would look first at tickPositions, where you can explicitly set the values, or at tickAmount, where you can specify that it show only two values, and it will still use its normal algorithm to determine them:  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickAmount | http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositions

Comment: I think tickPositions is what I am looking for, thanks, I'll investigate further based on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use also tickPositioner which extracts min/max from data and return array of two values.

```
yAxis: {
  tickPositioner: function() {
    return [this.dataMin, this.dataMax];
  }
},
```

Example:
- http://jsfiddle.net/rchdfb0z/

Comment: Nice - I didn't know the dataMin and max were exposed there. This does run into the same problem as noted on my answer [the ticks become the axis min and max], which can be fixed the same way (except that the max will still need to be calculated)

Comment: Yes, I'm voting this one up as well as the this.dataMin and dataMax is indeed a nice solution. Thanks

Comment: Just made a small test and it seems this.dataMin is always returning 0... that's very sad...

Comment: Scratch this, I updated highchart and it only does it when there are null values in the series data, I tried in the jsfiddle given by jlbriggs but I can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 3):

A demonstration of the tickPositions method:

First, define your data array and loop through it to find your min and max:

```
var chartData = [...], yMin, yMax;

$.each(chartData, function(i,point) {
    yMin = i == 0 ? point : (point < yMin ? point : yMin);
    yMax = i == 0 ? point : (point > yMax ? point : yMax);
});
```

Then, in your yAxis properties:

```
tickPositions: [Math.round(yMin), Math.round(yMax)],
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/9se1h970/

**EDIT for comment**

Ah, yes, of course.

You can fix the ticks being the absolute min and the max by adding a couple more properties to the y axis:

```
      min:0,
      max: (yMax * 1.1),
      startOnTick:false,
      endOnTick:false,
```

Updated example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/9se1h970/1/

Comment: I just tried that solution and it has an annoying side effect. defeinitely has an effect on the chart display (other than showing the axis ticks obviously) this means that it restricts the view between the lowest and the highest items in the array. Not sure I can use that then, it would be great to find a way to not influence the columns and just choose which ticks you display

Comment: Now we're talking! That's the best option so far!

Comment: @GeorgesLegros Looks good. You can eliminate the looping altogether in that case, too.

Comment: Indeed but that's just for the demo, my code does not look like that at all. Anyway I'm still facing a strange issue with this.dataMin being always 0 when some series data are null.

Comment: @GeorgesLegros Sounds possibly like a bug. I would think dataMin would ignore null values. Worth reporting perhaps. If it can't be worked out that way, you may need to loop through your data after all...

Comment: Funny thing is that in the jsfiddle, I do add null values manually in the data and the dataMin is not 0... might be in my code but I don't really find it...

Comment: Then it seems like you need to make sure that null is being passed correctly, and not in a format that is being interpreted as zero instead of null?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/vjLfqyct/).

All you have to do it is just:

1. define your Min and Max.
2. grab your data from your source (in this case is a Json file)
3. select only data between Ymin and Ymax
4. save them in a new array (arrData).

   $(function () {

   ```
       $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function (data) {
               var arrData=[];
           var i,Ymin,Ymax;
       Ymin=20;//minmun value of Y data
       Ymax=40;//max value of Y data

       //selec only data between Ymin and Ymax
       for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
           if(data[i][1]> Ymin && data[i][1]<Ymax){
           arrData.push(data[i][1]);
         };
       }

       // Create the chart
       $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


           rangeSelector : {
               selected : 1
           },

           title : {
               text : 'Min/Max Y data'
           },

           series : [{
               name : 'Min Max Y',
               data : arrData,
           }]
       });
   });
   ```

   });

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, you want to plot two lines on min and max values. This should be easily possible with **[Axis.addPlotLine](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotLine)**.
I would check the input data for min/max values and then add plot lines. As on this [DEMO](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/yaxis-plotlines).

Comment: Not really no, I am looking at displaying the min and max value in the axis and nothing else. The comment of @jlbriggs seem to be the correct answer

Comment: Actually, I might need to plot the line later on so that'll be useful too but it's just out of scope right now. Thanks anyway

Comment: A plot line with a label will essentially mimic the axis lines (minus a tick mark).  It is one of a variety of potential methods to get what you want.